# How make a SELECT between 2 dates( e.g. minutes) without having any datasets

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have no idea how to solve this:

I am struggling a bit - want to have a list in **MySql**/SQL or **MariaDB** of every minute (eg. timestamp) between two dates - without having an DB entry.

e.g.

```
StartDate 2020-05-30 08:01:00

EndDate 2020-05-30 12:01:00
```

Now i need a listing of every minute between those both stamps

Like

```
--> Select Minutes between StartDate and Enddate
```

### Listing

```
2020-05-30 08:01:00

2020-05-30 08:02:00

2020-05-30 08:03:00

2020-05-30 08:04:00
```

...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MariaDB only (since 10.0):

```
SELECT  '2020-05-30 08:01:00' + INTERVAL seq MINUTE
    FROM seq_0_to_241
    WHERE '2020-05-30 08:01:00' + INTERVAL seq MINUTE
       <= '2020-05-30 12:01:00';
```

(The "241" is optimal, but any larger number would also work.)

(MariaDB added CTEs in 10.2.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive ts as (
      select timestamp('2020-05-30 08:01:00') as ts
      union all
      select ts + interval 1 minute
      from ts
      where ts < '2020-05-30 12:01:00'
     )
select ts.ts
from ts;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f938d8ee384d0403473c94c7f1cf88d5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Note that recursive CTEs are not available in MySQL 5.x.

Comment: Thanks - In my client it is not working, cause the with - but for sure - your answer seems to be very good - Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LarsRönnbäck . . . That particular fact seems irrelevant when the question is tagged MariaDB.  In that database, they go back to 10.2.1 or about 2016.

Comment: @Tonnbo . . .Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?